# Why does focus not work on select list (Safari)

Tags: javascript, select, input, focus

This works fine:

```
    <input type="button" value="TEST123" onClick="insert('TEST123')">
```

But this doesn't focus in Safari, only in Firefox:

```
    <select>            
    <option value="TEST123" onClick="insert('TEST123')">TEST123</option>
    </select>
```

This is the javascript that should do the focus (and then input the text in the textarea):

```
function insert(Text) {
var input = document.forms['formular'].elements['eingabe'];
input.focus();
```

Why does it not focus in Safari?